# Saga entry table/ Sagas collection remains empty

Tags: java, spring, saga, axon

I've been following [AxonBank example](https://github.com/abuijze/webinar-axon-bank) in order to understand implementation of Saga in Axon framework and have some code like this for starting and ending saga

```
@Saga
public class MoneyTransferSaga {
    @Inject
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    private String targetAccount;
    private String transferId;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "transferId")
    public void on(MoneyTransferRequestedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Inside start saga for money transfer event");
        targetAccount = event.getTargetAccount();
        transferId = event.getTransferId();
        SagaLifecycle.associateWith("transactionId", transferId);
        System.out.println("## These are the params going into WMC : sourceAccount: " + event.getSourceAccount()
                + " transferID: " + transferId + " event.getAmount: " + event.getAmount());
        commandGateway.send(new WithdrawMoneyCommand(event.getSourceAccount(), transferId, event.getAmount()),
                new CommandCallback<WithdrawMoneyCommand, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(CommandMessage<? extends WithdrawMoneyCommand> commandMessage,
                            Object result) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(CommandMessage<? extends WithdrawMoneyCommand> commandMessage,
                            Throwable cause) {
                        System.out.println("On failure of withdraw money command inside saga ");
                        System.out.println("###################### Cause of failure = " + cause);
                        commandGateway.send(new CancelMoneyTransferCommand(event.getTransferId()));
                    }
                });
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "transactionId")
    public void on(MoneyWithdrawnEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Inside saga event handler for monney withdrawnevent");
        commandGateway.send(new DepositMoneyCommand(targetAccount, event.getTransactionId(), event.getAmount()),
                LoggingCallback.INSTANCE);
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "transactionId")
    public void on(MoneyDepositedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Inside saga event handler for money deposited event");
        commandGateway.send(new CompleteMoneyTransferCommand(transferId), LoggingCallback.INSTANCE);
    }

    @EndSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "transferId")
    public void on(MoneyTransferCompletedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Inside Endsaga for money transfer complete event");
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "transferId")
    public void on(MoneyTransferCancelledEvent event) {
        end();
    }
}
```

After performing the money transfer via the REST API all this code gets executed as I can see my logs getting printed to console and all transactions being stored in account table.

All entries exist in domain_event_entry also, but the saga_entry and association_value_entry tables remain empty regardless of whether the transaction is success or failure.

Initially I thought this might be because of a misconfigured saga store so I configured the saga store with `MongoSagaStore` but still the collection of Saga remains empty.

So am I missing something here or axon just deletes the data from these tables after the saga is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AxonFramework will automatically remove a Saga entry from its storage, including any associations, when it has ended. So you'll only ever see information of active instances, there.

In the sample application, all bus components use the "Simple..." implementation, which basically means all activities are executed in the same thread. Therefore, once you have received the OK nor NotOK, all activities by the Saga will have ended as well.
If you were to replace them with Async or Distributed implementations, this is no longer the case. You OK will be returned before the entire process has finished.

Comment: is there a way to override this behavior or Axon does it on purpose?

Comment: It is doing that on purpose because the 'complex business transaction' where the Saga stands for is rounded up. Something which is done does not necessarily have to linger. Additionally, the Saga Repository does not serve a querying purpose, it is just there as a way to store the 'complex business transaction' to be picked up at a later time.

Nonetheless, the simplest way to not have the saga removed is to not call the `SagaLifecycle.end()` function or add the `@EndSaga` annotation to any event handlers.

Comment: Not ending saga was my first thought I wondered if there was some configuration instead, but your explanation makes lots of sense, so technically the only trace of existence of Saga after the Saga ends is in domain_event_entry.

Comment: @Allard, I understand Saga's storage behavior of the AxonBank example. However in the AxonTrader example (https://github.com/AxonFramework/Axon-trader), the Sell/Buy Sagas will not finish within one thread, they could span multiple user interactions. However I am still not seeing any Saga persistence in SAGAENTRY table. Is it all done in memory? What will happen if there is a server restart? (I understand the example is using hsql in memory, I am saying if it is done in real database, the persistence behavior should still be the same). Any example showing Saga persistence will be very helpful.